# Regex Expression Required

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

i am new to this regex thing, how can we build regex expression for following thig

```
input==>[User:1490474408:michaelayliffe]

output should be ==>1490474408

input will be anything like below:

1.[User:1490474408:michaelayliffe]
2.[User:12345:dfhdfhdf]
3.[User:56789:utyutyutyu]
```

Output should be middle value.

Please reply.

Comment: Why don't you start by showing what you have tried? And while you're at it define the language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=\[User:)[^:]+
```

Using `lookbehind` should work for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
/\d+/g
```

It is find digits those are middle of your string